# R shiny update column value to check-box controls value on child rows on nested table

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, parent-child, dt

I would like to set check-box values to the corresponding values in column 'YN' when a child rows loads and after the user clicks/unclicks a checkbox I would like 'YN' column to update. I don't need check-boxes on parent rows. I've tried to modify an example I've found, but it's not working on child rows. Please suggest how to implement this correctly. Here is an example of code that works but doesn't update the 'YN' column. Thank you very much. Here is the code:

### data

```
      library(DT)
        
        dat <- data.frame(
          Sr = c(1.5, 2.3),
          Description = c("A - B", "X - Y")
        )
    ## details of row 1
subdat1 <- data.frame(
  Chromosome = c("chr18","chr4"),
  SNP = c("rs2","rs3"),
  YN = c(TRUE, FALSE),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
    shinyCheckbox <- function(id, values) {
      inputs <- character(length(values))
      for(i in seq_along(inputs)) {
        inputs[i] <- 
          as.character(
            checkboxInput(paste0(id, i), label = NULL, value = values[i], width = "20px")
          )
      }
      inputs
    }
    subdat1$check <- shinyCheckbox("check", subdat1$YN)
    ## details of row 2
    subdat2 <- data.frame(
      Chromosome = c("chr19","chr20"), 
      SNP = c("rs3","rs4"),
      YN = c(TRUE, FALSE),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

subdat2$check <- shinyCheckbox("check", subdat2$YN)
## merge the row details
subdats <- lapply(list(subdat1, subdat2), purrr::transpose)
## dataframe for the datatable


 Dat <- cbind(" " = "&oplus;", dat, details = I(subdats))

    ###spliting subdata into dataframes###

    subdat <- data.frame(
      Gene_SUB=c("MUTYH","AR"),
      Location_SUB=c("chr1:45797228","chr2:45797228"),
      Exon_SUB=c(NA,23),          
      HGVS_p_SUB=c("NP_001121897.1:p.(Gly396Asp)","NP_001121897.1:p.(Gly396Asp)"),
      stopA=c(45797278,114925456),
      YN = c(FALSE, FALSE),
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )
    
    maindat <- data.frame(
      Gene=c("MUTYH","AR"),
      Location=c("chr1:45797228","chr2:45797228"),
      Exon=c(NA,23),          
      HGVS_p=c("NP_001121897.1:p.(Gly396Asp)","NP_001121897.1:p.(Gly396Asp)"),
      stopA=c(45797278,114925456),
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )
    subdat$check <- shinyCheckbox("check", subdat$YN)
    
    fs<-split(subdat, factor(subdat$stopA, levels = unique(subdat$stopA)))
    subdats <- lapply(fs, purrr::transpose)
    oplus <- sapply(subdats, function(x) if(length(x)) "&oplus;" else "")
    Dat <- cbind(" " = oplus, maindat, details = I(subdats))
    
## the callback
callback = JS(
  "$('[id^=check]').on('click', function(){",
  "  var id = this.getAttribute('id');",
  "  var i = parseInt(/check(\\d+)/.exec(id)[1]);",
  "  var value = $(this).prop('checked');",
  "  var cell = table.cell(i-1, 2).data(value).draw();",
  "})",
  "table.column(1).nodes().to$().css({cursor: 'pointer'});",
  "// Format the nested table into another table",
  "var childId = function(d){",
  "  var tail = d.slice(2, d.length - 1);",
  "  return 'child_' + tail.join('_').replace(/[\\s|\\.|'|,|\\(|\\)]/g, '_');",
  "};",
  "var format = function (d) {",
  "  if (d != null) {",
  "    var id = childId(d);",
  "    var html = ", 
  "          '<table class=\"display compact\" id=\"' + id + '\"><thead><tr>';",
  "    for (var key in d[d.length-1][0]) {",
  "      html += '<th>' + key + '</th>';",
  "    }",
  "    html += '</tr></thead></table>'",
  "    return html;",
  "  } else {",
  "    return '';",
  "  }",
  "};",
  "var rowCallback = function(row, dat, displayNum, index){",
  "  if($(row).hasClass('odd')){",
  "    for(var j=0; j<dat.length; j++){",
  "      $('td:eq('+j+')', row).css('background-color', 'papayawhip');",
  "    }",
  "  } else {",
  "    for(var j=0; j<dat.length; j++){",
  "      $('td:eq('+j+')', row).css('background-color', 'lemonchiffon');",
  "    }",
  "  }",
  "};",
  "var headerCallback = function(thead, data, start, end, display){",
  "  $('th', thead).css({",
  "    'border-top': '3px solid indigo',", 
  "    'color': 'indigo',",
  "    'background-color': '#fadadd'",
  "  });",
  "};",
  "var format_datatable = function (d) {",
  "  var dataset = [];",
  "  var n = d.length - 1;",
  "  for (var i = 0; i < d[n].length; i++) {",
  "    var datarow = $.map(d[n][i], function (value, index) {",
  "      return [value];",
  "    });",
  "    dataset.push(datarow);",
  "  }",
  "  var id = 'table#' + childId(d);",
  "  var subtable = $(id).DataTable({",
  "                     'data': dataset,",
  "                     'autoWidth': true,",
  "                     'deferRender': true,",
  "                     'info': false,",
  "                     'lengthChange': false,",
  "                     'ordering': d[n].length > 1,",
  "                     'order': [],",
  "                     'paging': false,",
  "                     'scrollX': false,",
  "                     'scrollY': false,",
  "                     'searching': false,",
  "                     'sortClasses': false,",
  "                     'rowCallback': rowCallback,",
  "                     'headerCallback': headerCallback,",
  "                     'columnDefs': [{targets: '_all', className: 'dt-center'}]",
  "                   });",
  "};",
  "table.on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {",
  "  var td = $(this),",
  "      row = table.row(td.closest('tr'));",
  "  if (row.child.isShown()) {",
  "    row.child.hide();",
  "    td.html('&oplus;');",
  "  } else {",
  "    row.child(format(row.data())).show();",
  "    td.html('&CircleMinus;');",
  "    format_datatable(row.data());",
  "  }",
  "});")

## datatable

datatable(Dat, callback = callback, escape = FALSE,
          options = list(
            columnDefs = list(
              list(visible = FALSE, targets = ncol(Dat)),
              list(orderable = FALSE, className = 'details-control', targets = 1),
              list(className = "dt-center", targets = "_all")
            )
            #preDrawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
            #drawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } ')
          ),
          
          )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
library(DT)
library(shiny)

shinyCheckbox <- function(id, values) {
  inputs <- character(length(values))
  for(i in seq_along(inputs)) {
    inputs[i] <- 
      as.character(
        checkboxInput(paste0(id, i), label = NULL, value = values[i], width = "20px")
      )
  }
  inputs
}

NestedData <- function(dat, children){
  stopifnot(length(children) == nrow(dat))
  g <- function(d){
    if(is.data.frame(d)){
      purrr::transpose(d)
    }else{
      purrr::transpose(NestedData(d[[1]], children = d$children))
    }
  }
  subdats <- lapply(children, g)
  oplus <- ifelse(lengths(subdats), "&oplus;", "") 
  cbind(" " = oplus, dat, "_details" = I(subdats), 
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}

dat <- data.frame(
  Sr = c(1.5, 2.3),
  Description = c("A - B", "X - Y")
)
## details of row 1
subdat1 <- data.frame(
  Chromosome = c("chr18","chr4"),
  SNP = c("rs2","rs3"),
  YN = c(TRUE, FALSE),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
subdat1$check <- shinyCheckbox("check", subdat1$YN)

## details of row 2
subdat2 <- data.frame(
  Chromosome = c("chr19","chr20"), 
  SNP = c("rs3","rs4"),
  YN = c(TRUE, FALSE),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
subdat2$check <- shinyCheckbox("check", subdat2$YN)

Dat <- NestedData(dat, list(subdat1, subdat2))

## whether to show row names
rowNames = FALSE
colIdx <- as.integer(rowNames)

## the callback
parentRows <- which(Dat[,1] != "")
callback <- JS(
  sprintf("var parentRows = [%s];", toString(parentRows-1)),
  sprintf("var j0 = %d;", colIdx),
  "var nrows = table.rows().count();",
  "for(let i = 0; i < nrows; ++i){",
  "  var $cell = table.cell(i,j0).nodes().to$();",
  "  if(parentRows.indexOf(i) > -1){",
  "    $cell.css({cursor: 'pointer'});",
  "  }else{",
  "    $cell.removeClass('details-control');",
  "  }",
  "}",
  "",
  "// --- make the table header of the nested table --- //",
  "var formatHeader = function(d, childId){",
  "  if(d !== null){",
  "    var html = ", 
  "      '<table class=\"display compact hover\" ' + ",
  "      'style=\"padding-left: 30px;\" id=\"' + childId + ", 
  "      '\"><thead><tr>';",
  "    var data = d[d.length-1] || d._details;",
  "    for(let key in data[0]){",
  "      html += '<th>' + key + '</th>';",
  "    }",
  "    html += '</tr></thead></table>'",
  "    return html;",
  "  } else {",
  "    return '';",
  "  }",
  "};",
  "",
  "// --- row callback to style rows of child tables --- //",
  "var rowCallback = function(row, dat, displayNum, index){",
  "  if($(row).hasClass('odd')){",
  "    $(row).css('background-color', 'papayawhip');",
  "    $(row).hover(function(){",
  "      $(this).css('background-color', '#E6FF99');",
  "    }, function(){",
  "      $(this).css('background-color', 'papayawhip');",
  "    });",
  "  } else {",
  "    $(row).css('background-color', 'lemonchiffon');",
  "    $(row).hover(function(){",
  "      $(this).css('background-color', '#DDFF75');",
  "    }, function(){",
  "      $(this).css('background-color', 'lemonchiffon');",
  "    });",
  "  }",
  "};",
  "",
  "// --- header callback to style header of child tables --- //",
  "var headerCallback = function(thead, data, start, end, display){",
  "  $('th', thead).css({",
  "    'border-top': '3px solid indigo',", 
  "    'color': 'indigo',",
  "    'background-color': '#fadadd'",
  "  });",
  "};",
  "",
  "// --- make the datatable --- //",
  "var formatDatatable = function(d, childId){",
  "  var data = d[d.length-1] || d._details;",
  "  var colNames = Object.keys(data[0]);",
  "  var columns = colNames.map(function(x){",
  "    return {data: x.replace(/\\./g, '\\\\\\.'), title: x};",
  "  });",
  "  var id = 'table#' + childId;",
  "  var subtable;",
  "  if(colNames.indexOf('_details') === -1){",
  "    subtable = $(id).DataTable({",
  "      'data': data,",
  "      'columns': columns,",
  "      'autoWidth': true,",
  "      'deferRender': true,",
  "      'info': false,",
  "      'lengthChange': false,",
  "      'ordering': data.length > 1,",
  "      'order': [],",
  "      'paging': false,",
  "      'scrollX': false,",
  "      'scrollY': false,",
  "      'searching': false,",
  "      'sortClasses': false,",
  "      'rowCallback': rowCallback,",
  "      'headerCallback': headerCallback,",
  "      'columnDefs': [{targets: '_all', className: 'dt-center'}]",
  "    });",
  "  } else {",
  "    subtable = $(id).DataTable({",
  "      'data': data,",
  "      'columns': columns,",
  "      'autoWidth': true,",
  "      'deferRender': true,",
  "      'info': false,",
  "      'lengthChange': false,",
  "      'ordering': data.length > 1,",
  "      'order': [],",
  "      'paging': false,",
  "      'scrollX': false,",
  "      'scrollY': false,",
  "      'searching': false,",
  "      'sortClasses': false,",
  "      'rowCallback': rowCallback,",
  "      'headerCallback': headerCallback,",
  "      'columnDefs': [", 
  "        {targets: -1, visible: false},", 
  "        {targets: 0, orderable: false, className: 'details-control'},", 
  "        {targets: '_all', className: 'dt-center'}",
  "      ]",
  "    }).column(0).nodes().to$().css({cursor: 'pointer'});",
  "  }", # THIS IS THE CODE I ADDED TO DEAL WITH THE CHECKBOXES:
  "  $(id).on('click', '[id^=check]', function(){",
  "    var id = this.getAttribute('id');",
  "    var i = parseInt(/check(\\d+)/.exec(id)[1]);",
  "    var value = $(this).prop('checked');",
  "    subtable.cell(i-1, 2).data(value).draw();",
  "  });",
  "};",
  "",
  "// --- display the child table on click --- //",
  "// array to store id's of already created child tables",
  "var children = [];", 
  "table.on('click', 'td.details-control', function(){",
  "  var tbl = $(this).closest('table'),",
  "      tblId = tbl.attr('id'),",
  "      td = $(this),",
  "      row = $(tbl).DataTable().row(td.closest('tr')),",
  "      rowIdx = row.index();",
  "  if(row.child.isShown()){",
  "    row.child.hide();",
  "    td.html('&oplus;');",
  "  } else {",
  "    var childId = tblId + '-child-' + rowIdx;",
  "    if(children.indexOf(childId) === -1){", 
  "      // this child has not been created yet",
  "      children.push(childId);",
  "      row.child(formatHeader(row.data(), childId)).show();",
  "      td.html('&CircleMinus;');",
  "      formatDatatable(row.data(), childId, rowIdx);",
  "    }else{",
  "      // this child has already been created",
  "      row.child(true);",
  "      td.html('&CircleMinus;');",
  "    }",
  "  }",
  "});")

datatable(
  Dat, 
  callback = callback, rownames = rowNames, escape = -colIdx-1,
  options = list(
    paging = FALSE,
    searching = FALSE,
    columnDefs = list(
      list(
        visible = FALSE, 
        targets = ncol(Dat)-1+colIdx
      ),
      list(
        orderable = FALSE, 
        className = "details-control", 
        targets = colIdx
      ),
      list(
        className = "dt-center", 
        targets = "_all"
      )
    )
  )
)
```

---

If you have a Shiny app and you want to update `subdat1/2` when the checkboxes are clicked, you can do as follows (I changed the callback):

```r
library(DT)
library(shiny)

shinyCheckbox <- function(id, values) {
  inputs <- character(length(values))
  for(i in seq_along(inputs)) {
    inputs[i] <- 
      as.character(
        checkboxInput(paste0(id, i), label = NULL, value = values[i], width = "20px")
      )
  }
  inputs
}

NestedData <- function(dat, children){
  stopifnot(length(children) == nrow(dat))
  g <- function(d){
    if(is.data.frame(d)){
      purrr::transpose(d)
    }else{
      purrr::transpose(NestedData(d[[1]], children = d$children))
    }
  }
  subdats <- lapply(children, g)
  oplus <- ifelse(lengths(subdats), "&oplus;", "") 
  cbind(" " = oplus, dat, "_details" = I(subdats), 
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}

dat <- data.frame(
  Sr = c(1.5, 2.3),
  Description = c("A - B", "X - Y")
)
## details of row 1
subdat1 <- data.frame(
  Chromosome = c("chr18","chr4"),
  SNP = c("rs2","rs3"),
  YN = c(TRUE, FALSE),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
subdat1$check <- shinyCheckbox("check", subdat1$YN)

## details of row 2
subdat2 <- data.frame(
  Chromosome = c("chr19","chr20"), 
  SNP = c("rs3","rs4"),
  YN = c(TRUE, FALSE),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
subdat2$check <- shinyCheckbox("check", subdat2$YN)

Dat <- NestedData(dat, list(subdat1, subdat2))

## whether to show row names
rowNames = FALSE
colIdx <- as.integer(rowNames)

## the callback
parentRows <- which(Dat[,1] != "")
callback <- JS(
  sprintf("var parentRows = [%s];", toString(parentRows-1)),
  sprintf("var j0 = %d;", colIdx),
  "var nrows = table.rows().count();",
  "for(let i = 0; i < nrows; ++i){",
  "  var $cell = table.cell(i,j0).nodes().to$();",
  "  if(parentRows.indexOf(i) > -1){",
  "    $cell.css({cursor: 'pointer'});",
  "  }else{",
  "    $cell.removeClass('details-control');",
  "  }",
  "}",
  "",
  "// --- make the table header of the nested table --- //",
  "var formatHeader = function(d, childId){",
  "  if(d !== null){",
  "    var html = ", 
  "      '<table class=\"display compact hover\" ' + ",
  "      'style=\"padding-left: 30px;\" id=\"' + childId + ", 
  "      '\"><thead><tr>';",
  "    var data = d[d.length-1] || d._details;",
  "    for(let key in data[0]){",
  "      html += '<th>' + key + '</th>';",
  "    }",
  "    html += '</tr></thead></table>'",
  "    return html;",
  "  } else {",
  "    return '';",
  "  }",
  "};",
  "",
  "// --- row callback to style rows of child tables --- //",
  "var rowCallback = function(row, dat, displayNum, index){",
  "  if($(row).hasClass('odd')){",
  "    $(row).css('background-color', 'papayawhip');",
  "    $(row).hover(function(){",
  "      $(this).css('background-color', '#E6FF99');",
  "    }, function(){",
  "      $(this).css('background-color', 'papayawhip');",
  "    });",
  "  } else {",
  "    $(row).css('background-color', 'lemonchiffon');",
  "    $(row).hover(function(){",
  "      $(this).css('background-color', '#DDFF75');",
  "    }, function(){",
  "      $(this).css('background-color', 'lemonchiffon');",
  "    });",
  "  }",
  "};",
  "",
  "// --- header callback to style header of child tables --- //",
  "var headerCallback = function(thead, data, start, end, display){",
  "  $('th', thead).css({",
  "    'border-top': '3px solid indigo',", 
  "    'color': 'indigo',",
  "    'background-color': '#fadadd'",
  "  });",
  "};",
  "",
  "// --- make the datatable --- //",
  "var formatDatatable = function(d, childId){",
  "  var data = d[d.length-1] || d._details;",
  "  var colNames = Object.keys(data[0]);",
  "  var columns = colNames.map(function(x){",
  "    return {data: x.replace(/\\./g, '\\\\\\.'), title: x};",
  "  });",
  "  var id = 'table#' + childId;",
  "  var subtable;",
  "  if(colNames.indexOf('_details') === -1){",
  "    subtable = $(id).DataTable({",
  "      'data': data,",
  "      'columns': columns,",
  "      'autoWidth': true,",
  "      'deferRender': true,",
  "      'info': false,",
  "      'lengthChange': false,",
  "      'ordering': data.length > 1,",
  "      'order': [],",
  "      'paging': false,",
  "      'scrollX': false,",
  "      'scrollY': false,",
  "      'searching': false,",
  "      'sortClasses': false,",
  "      'rowCallback': rowCallback,",
  "      'headerCallback': headerCallback,",
  "      'columnDefs': [{targets: '_all', className: 'dt-center'}]",
  "    });",
  "  } else {",
  "    subtable = $(id).DataTable({",
  "      'data': data,",
  "      'columns': columns,",
  "      'autoWidth': true,",
  "      'deferRender': true,",
  "      'info': false,",
  "      'lengthChange': false,",
  "      'ordering': data.length > 1,",
  "      'order': [],",
  "      'paging': false,",
  "      'scrollX': false,",
  "      'scrollY': false,",
  "      'searching': false,",
  "      'sortClasses': false,",
  "      'rowCallback': rowCallback,",
  "      'headerCallback': headerCallback,",
  "      'columnDefs': [", 
  "        {targets: -1, visible: false},", 
  "        {targets: 0, orderable: false, className: 'details-control'},", 
  "        {targets: '_all', className: 'dt-center'}",
  "      ]",
  "    }).column(0).nodes().to$().css({cursor: 'pointer'});",
  "  }", # THIS IS THE CODE I ADDED TO DEAL WITH THE CHECKBOXES:
  "  $(id).on('click', '[id^=check]', function(){",
  "    var id = this.getAttribute('id');",
  "    var i = parseInt(/check(\\d+)/.exec(id)[1]);",
  "    var value = $(this).prop('checked');",
  "    subtable.cell(i-1, 2).data(value).draw();",
  "    Shiny.setInputValue('update', {child: childId, row: i, value: value});",
  "  });",
  "};",
  "",
  "// --- display the child table on click --- //",
  "// array to store id's of already created child tables",
  "var children = [];", 
  "table.on('click', 'td.details-control', function(){",
  "  var tbl = $(this).closest('table'),",
  "      tblId = tbl.attr('id'),",
  "      td = $(this),",
  "      row = $(tbl).DataTable().row(td.closest('tr')),",
  "      rowIdx = row.index();",
  "  if(row.child.isShown()){",
  "    row.child.hide();",
  "    td.html('&oplus;');",
  "  } else {",
  "    var childId = tblId + '-child-' + rowIdx;",
  "    if(children.indexOf(childId) === -1){", 
  "      // this child has not been created yet",
  "      children.push(childId);",
  "      row.child(formatHeader(row.data(), childId)).show();",
  "      td.html('&CircleMinus;');",
  "      formatDatatable(row.data(), childId, rowIdx);",
  "    }else{",
  "      // this child has already been created",
  "      row.child(true);",
  "      td.html('&CircleMinus;');",
  "    }",
  "  }",
  "});")

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  actionButton("print", "Print child rows"),
  br(),
  DTOutput("dtable")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output[["dtable"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      Dat, 
      callback = callback, rownames = rowNames, escape = -colIdx-1,
      selection = "none",
      options = list(
        paging = FALSE,
        searching = FALSE,
        columnDefs = list(
          list(
            visible = FALSE, 
            targets = ncol(Dat)-1+colIdx
          ),
          list(
            orderable = FALSE, 
            className = "details-control", 
            targets = colIdx
          ),
          list(
            className = "dt-center", 
            targets = "_all"
          )
        )
      )
    )
  })
  
  observeEvent(input[["update"]], {
    child <- 
      stringr::str_extract(input[["update"]][["child"]], "\\d+$")
    row <- as.integer(input[["update"]][["row"]])
    value <- input[["update"]][["value"]]
    if(child == "0") {
      subdat1[row, "YN"] <<- value
    } else if(child == "1") {
      subdat2[row, "YN"] <<- value
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(input[["print"]], {
    print(subdat1$YN)
    print(subdat2$YN)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks, how do I force the code to update subdat2 dataframe after the check is clicked? when I print subdat2$YN is still shows values before the checkbox was clicked and I would like to update.

Comment: @user3781528 What do you mean by "print subdat2$YN"? You're in a Shiny app?

Comment: Thank you, I need more time to test the second example. I split subdata into dataframes and bind to main data. Visually the table looks fine but checkboxes only update for the child of the first parent. Could you please tell me why if fails? I've updated the question with a small example. You need to adjust col # in your JS code for updating, since 'YN' is a different column number. Many Thanks

Comment: good solution, but perhaps there is a way to avoid hardcoding of subdata names?

Comment: @user3781528 You can get all the subdata in a list by doing `lapply(lapply(Dat$`_details`, purrr::transpose), function(x) {as.data.frame(lapply(x, unlist))})`.

Comment: Any suggestion how to hide columns in nested datatable,Parents/Child? For example how to hide 'YN' column in child rows?

Comment: @user3781528 Hmm good question! Sorry but I don't see right now. I will think about that.

Comment: @user3781528 <https://stackoverflow.com/q/78077819/1100107>

Comment: As I was doing more testing, I've discovered that if user sorts the table, thus changing the order of parents/or children. I can't get the correct parent/child to update 'YN' column after a checkbox is clicked. Is there a way to get the correct parent/child after sorting/filtering. Thanks